# how to save a single field value from mongoDB collection into a var?

Tags: mongoose

i have this code:

connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
connection.once('open', function () {

```
connection.db.collection("seekers", function(err, collection){
    collection.find({field: 'electric engineer'}).toArray(function(err, data){
       var mail = data;
       var description = data;
        console.log(data); // it will print your collection data
        console.log(mail); 
        console.log(description);
    })
});
```

});

i want to save the mail value and the description in 2 separate variables.

i get undefined value.

how can i do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://YourUriHere', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(mongoose => {
mongoose.connection.db.collection('yourCollectionName').find({}, { projection: { fieldYouWant: 1, anotherFieldYouWant: 1 }}).toArray(function (err, info) {
    console.log("info: ", err);
    console.log("info: ", info);
})})
```

I recommend it's better to use Schemas if you use mongoose.